Allow user to choose between peer dependencies
I'm trying to build a framework that expects a config provided by another library.
That library has two versions: @library/core and @library/react, both of which provide a function to create the config. (@library/react simply re-exports the config helper from @library/core).
Is there any way I can specify in my peer dependencies that the user has to install one of these, but it can be any one of these?
